# NullPointerException when setting a panel layout to null?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am attempting to create a GUI where the layout is null so that I can easily create and erase images with pixel dimensions, however I receive a NullPointerException when I try to do so.

According to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html, simply setting the layout to null should suffice, however when I do it I receive the NullPointerException.

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.util.*;

public class DriverClass extends JFrame {
  /*
   * The frame to contain all GUI.
   */
  public JFrame frame;
  /*
   * The Panel to contain all GUI.
   */
  public JPanel panel;
  /*
   * Class constructor
   */
  public DriverClass () {
   setSize(400,400);
   JPanel panel = new JPanel();
   panel.setSize(400,400);
   panel.setLayout(null); //NullPointerException occurs here
   add(panel);
   setVisible(true);
   panel.setVisible(true);
   frame.pack();
  }
  /*
   * The main method that runs the example class
   */
  public static void main (String[] args) {

    DriverClass driver = new DriverClass();

  }
}
```

What I expect is a simple working JFrame for me to add images to (through another class) however I am instead prevented from the first step. The error is as follows:

```
    at TextDriverClass.<init>(TextDriverClass.java:40)
    at TextDriverClass.main(TextDriverClass.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:267)
```

The line the first error line points to is indicated in the comments of the code. Please note that I have not created any components or children other than the JPanel so I should not have to worry about using setbounds() or repaint() yet.

Comment: what do you want to achieve by setting layout to null, if you see clear Exception there?

Comment: @user8426627 It seems to me to be the easiest way to manage larger quantities of images (~50) at once using a pixel grid, as I want to handle each image independently without worrying about how they interact with other images. [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html) tells me that this is doable, so I am assuming that only a minor problem is preventing me from using it. The only glaring problem with null layout is that it is ruined by window resizing, however I don't mind that at all because I plan on making a fixed window.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is not in the line you are indicating; but in:

```
frame.pack()
```

The field `frame` is `null` and that's what giving you the NPE. I think you are meaning to invoke:

```
this.pack()
```

since your `DriverClass` already extends `JFrame`. In such case, you really don't need the `public JFrame frame` field.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, this fixed it. I believe I was born stupid and misread the line location of the error.

Comment: good point. also he has public JPanel panel and makes inside the constructor local JPanel panel, means this.panel  will be 0